# Small question about export and $() double quotes

Tags: bash, quotes

When I write `export X="test"` in a file `test.sh` and do `$(cat test.sh)` in shell quote stay, i.e. `echo $X` gives `"test"` whereas `export X="test"` directly in shell makes quotes disappear, i.e. `echo $X` gives `test` why ?

I seem to be executing the same code and it has been messing with my paths :)

Comment: There's a very cool wiki on it over [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)

Comment: You *seem* to be executing the same code; you are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two is quote removal. From the man page,

> Quote Removal
>
> After the preceding expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the characters \, ', and " that did not result from
>          one of the above expansions are removed.

In `$(cat test.sh)`, the eventual command contains unquoted `"` characters that did result from a command substitution. The command substitution produced `export X="test"`, which splits into the command word `export` and its literal argument `X="test"`.

In `export X="test"`, the command is again `export` with an argument `X="test"`, *but* those quotes are unquoted and were not produced by any expansions, so they are removed. The result is the command `export` receiving `X=test` (not `X="test"`) as its argument.

Each `export` command then splits its argument on the `=`, seeing `X` as the variable to define. One sees a right-hand side of `test` to use as a value, the other sees `"test"` to use as the value, resulting in the different assignments that you observed.

Answer (score 0):

Given a file `test.sh` that contains the phrase `export X="test"` the command `cat test.sh` outputs the string with escaped double-quotes `export X=\"test\"` which evaluates when printed in the bash console as `export X="test"`.

Which is why I was under the impression that I executed the same code, however in the first case I was affecting `\"test\"` to `X` while in the second I was affecting `test` to it.

The solution that I first used and then saw elsewhere is to pipe the output of `cat` to `sed 's/"//g'`, note the single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`.

Thanks to Hendrik Prinsloo for the reference above.

Comment: It's a subtle distinction, but it's not outputting escaped `"`s; the unescaped `"`s simply aren't subject to quote removal in this situation (because they are the result of an expansion, not part of the original input).